# Prevent screen rotation on Android

Tags: android, rotation, screen

I have one of my activities which I would like to prevent from rotating because I'm starting an AsyncTask, and screen rotation makes it restart.

Is there a way to tell this activity "DO NOT ROTATE the screen even if the user is shaking his phone like mad"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android

Comment: You can deal with screen orientation change *and* AsyncTasks. Preventing screen orientation changes is just a lazy workaround. And it's not hard to keep an AsyncTask alive across orientation changes :)

Comment: http://clamernotes.blogspot.com/2011/04/disable-screen-rotation-at-runtime-on.html

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful to actually provide a solution or some code, Romain, rather than just asserting "a solution exists and it is not hard".

Comment: you can use             `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);`

Answer (score 532, accepted):

Add

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

or

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

to the `<activity>` element/s in
the manifest and you're done.

Comment: Please note this is just hiding a bug in your app, making it less likely for users to trip over it.  But they still will.  Any configuration change can cause your activity to restart.  You really need to write your activity correctly to deal with the async task as it restarts.

Comment: This did not work for me in one case. I had the screen set to landscape before opening the app. When I opened the app, the screen rotated to portrait and caused a second call to asynctask.

Comment: You need to set things to "open in portrait mode" *AND* "always stay in portrait mode".  Doing only 1 is pointless.

Comment: @ibedogni - My God thank you!!! i have been wracking my brains over screen rotation problems when using `MediaRecorder` because screen rotation causes the required `SurfaceView` to be lost which breaks the recording task. Forcing this screen orientation solves my problem...this after after trying SO MANY other hacks ... i can't believe i didn't find this solution till now haha. Cheers, truly.

Comment: @hackbod regardless, this is the number #1 google hit for "android app prevent screen rotation," my need has nothing to do with async tasks

Comment: @hackbod How do we then write our activity correctly to deal with this problem?

Comment: As @Sara points out you need to add this to the <activity> tag for each activity you want to lock rather than to the <application> tag.

Comment: This is not the correct answer. What if one wants her activity not to rotate in any situation, regardless of being initially opened in each portrait/landscape modes.

Comment: Landscape should only be used in games, and video player. I have no idea why people support both modes.

Comment: This was my solution for a long time until I started using "loading screens" that would have a transparent background and spinning icon. If your screen orientation is not the original "landscape" or "portrait," meaning the screen is flipped, this code will flip your screen over when the loading starts. The user will have to flip their device or turn it over again to re-orient the screen after.

Comment: Note : When you turn on auto rate from the top menu, your app will still rotate

Answer (score 133):

You can follow the logic below to prevent auto rotate screen *while* your `AsyncTask` is running:

1. Store your current screen orientation inside your activity using [`getRequestedOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getRequestedOrientation%28%29).
2. Disable auto screen orientation using [`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29).
3. Run/execute your `AsyncTask`.
4. At the end of your `AsyncTask` restore your previous orientation status using [`setRequestedOrientation(oldOrientation)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation%28int%29).

Please note that there are several ways to access `Activity` (which runs on UI thread) properties inside an `AsyncTask`. You can implement your `AsyncTask` as an inner class or you can use message [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) that poke your `Activiy` class.

Comment: great idea :) you don't have store your current screen orientation you can use ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED

Comment: This seems incredible, @emre, thanks!  It seems **"Too good to be true!"** Notice the huge amount of discussion about the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3821423/294884 ... android experts, is there any downside here?!  Thanks again .. so much.

Comment: Crap!! This **DOES NOT WORK** if the device happens to BEGIN IN LANDSCAPE MODE.  What the hell!  Sux  :O

Comment: @Emre, This code doesn't work in certain cases. E.g. if the user changed his orientation between the start of your AsyncTask and the end of it. You would have saved and restored the wrong orientation then.

Answer (score 35):

The easiest way I found to do this was to put

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

within onCreate, just after

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

so...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

Answer (score 28):

In your Manifest file, for each Activity that you want to lock the screen rotation add: if you want to lock it in horizontal mode:

```
<activity
        ...
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

or if you want to lock it in vertical mode:

```
<activity
            ...
            ...
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 8):

Rather than going into the AndroidManifest, you could just do this:

```
screenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LOCKED);
... AsyncTask

screenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String things) {
    context.setRequestedOrientation(PlayListFragment.screenOrientation);
    or 
    context.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR);
}
```

The only drawback here is that it requires API level 18 or higher. So basically this is the tip of the spear.

Comment: This part is disabling home and recent apps button and even after releasing lock with SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR, its in disabled state. In Android N.

Answer (score 6):

**Activity.java**

```
@Override     
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       
        try {     
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);      
            if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {      
                // land      
            } else if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {      
               // port       
            }    
        } catch (Exception ex) {       
     }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <activity android:name="QRCodeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
   <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>

 </application>
```

Answer (score 4):

User `"portrait"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file might seem like a good solution. But it forces certain devices (that work best in landscape) to go into portrait, not getting the proper orientation. On the latest Android version, you will get wearing an error. So my suggestion it's better to use `"nosensor"`.

```
<activity
        ...
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml

**[ app > src > main > AndroidManifest.xml ]**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="xxx.zzzzzz.yyyyy">

   <uses-permission android:name="A-PERMISSION" />

   <application>
      <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:configChanges="orientation">
      </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following attribute on the ACTIVITY in AndroidManifest.xml is all you need:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

So, the full activity node would be:

```
<activity android:name="Activity1"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon"
          android:label="App Name"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:configChanges="orientation">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
        ...
        ...
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prevent Screen Rotation just add this following line in your Manifests.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

android:screenOrientation="portrait"
on application tag <application

and

<activity
...
...
android:screenOrientation="locked">

Comment: It's not really clear what to do with what is written, where to write it. Also, there are similar and more clear answers in the list, so not really needed answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Android Developer Tools](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adt.html) (ADT) and [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29)
you can go to your AndroidManifest.xml --> *Application* tab --> go down and select your activity. Finally, select your preferred orientation.
You can select one of the many options.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following code in the manifest.xml file.
The activity for which it should not rotate, in that activity add this element

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Then  it will not rotate.

Answer (score 0):

You can try This way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.itclanbd.spaceusers">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Login_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **AsyncTaskLoader** to keep your data safe even if the activity changes, instead of using **AsyncTask** that is a better way to build apps than preventing screen rotation.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this, The simplest way is to specify the desired orientation for each activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Open the *AndroidManifest.xml* file, Locate the `<activity>` tag for the activity you want to disable landscape mode for. Add the `android:screenOrientation` attribute to the `<activity>` tag and set its value to **nosensor** or **portrait**.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
   ...
   >
....
</activity>
```

You can read the full answer with details **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77523332/7756492)**