# Android application having problems on rotation

Tags: android, rotation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable orientation change in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512045/how-to-disable-orientation-change-in-android)

I'm trying to produce an Android application. How can I prevent the application to rotate to the right and to the left even when the user rotates their device?

Answer (score 2):

By setting the orientation you want in the **manifest**...

Example: Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` to the element in the manifest or landscape:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name="QRCodeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Also check Stack Overflow question *[Prevent screen rotation on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9123421/1434631)*.

Comment: I tried to place that line in the xml file in the <RelativeLayout>. It didn't help me. Can you be a little more specific where to place that line?

Comment: I tried this also and it didn't help, in addition I tried the other question that you mentioned. Perhaps you didn't understand me. I'm looking for a way that the application won't change and won't rotate even if the user tilt its phone