# How to keep android rotation landscape always

Tags: android, orientation, landscape

I want to keep landscape mode always.
I Lock screen to portrait mode on Nexus7, I set android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" and android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"in AndroidManifest.xml, when I go to other activity and back to this activity, then the screen will rotate portrait and rotate to landscape again (Didn't call onCreate method again), but I don't want to rotate the screen in any situations, how to fix it?

Comment: `he screen will rotate portrait and rotate to landscape again `. Can you explain this again please? You can also try adding `screenSize` to `configChanges`. i.e `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: `screenOrientation:landscape` in the `<activity...` tag in your Manifest.

Comment: I mean the nexus7's screen will rotate 90 to portrait mode, and then rotate 90 to landscape automatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent screen rotation on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answere you're looking for: 
[stackoverflow.com/a/2730894/2249774](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2730894/2249774)

Answer (score 1):

For All your Activities in the manifest set

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Example :-

```
<activity android:name="com.example.test.testActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"     android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.test.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Repeat this for all activities used in the manifest..

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your AndroidManifest.xml to look like  this

```
<activity
            android:name=".YOURACTIVITYNAME"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest file, try typing in the following code:

```
        android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

example:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.Quiz"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_quiz"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:parentActivityName="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.SignLanguageMenu" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.gaspar.slinfilipino.SignLanguageMenu" />
       </activity>
```