# make disable fullscreen in recyclerView

Tags: java, android

I do AndroidStudio project.
I did recyclerview as a checklist, so I need that fullscreen doesn't work, because it doesn't add any new information, only which in activity. Maybe you know a method :)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ndogac which code? as i understand i should add ClickListener but i don't have any code except clicking on item in checklist

Comment: what do you mean by fullscreen? you mean fullscreen activity? what does that have to do with adding values to your RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: maybe your mean is this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730855/prevent-screen-rotation-on-android

Comment: I mean that when user clicks on element of recycler view then "window" opens (where is additional information ) and i want to disable this function