# how to finish all activities and close the application in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

My application has the following flow:

Home->screen 1->screen 2->screen 3->screen 4->screen 5>Home->screen 2->Home->Screen 3

My problem is that when I am trying to close the application then Home activity opens everytime when I am trying to close the application.

I just want to close the application when user presses the back key of device on home screen.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758462/android-finish-all-activities

Answer (score 88, accepted):

There is [finishAffinity()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()) method that will finish the current activity and all parent activities, but it works only in Android 4.1 or higher.

Comment: still leaves children activities...  ex:  mainactivity launchmode is singleInstance, settings menu is launched, services calls startactivity on mainactivity, mainactivity calls finishAffinity...  settings menu is not finished...    this is not contrived, i'm writing an app launched and finished by bluetooth...  seems like broadcastreceivers in each open activity are required to make sure everything closes in all situations

Comment: finishAffinity / finish works on the back-stack. Its not necessarily killing its parent activity. The child activity can get launched in a separate task..

Answer (score 16):

This works well for me.

- You should using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flags.

  ```java
  Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, CloseActivity.class);
  //Clear all activities and start new task
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
  startActivity(intent);
  ```
- `onCreate()` method of `CloseActivity` activity.

  ```java
  @Override 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      finish(); // Exit 
  }
  ```

Comment: intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Use `finishAffinity()` method that will finish the current activity and all parent activities. But it works only for `API 16+` mean Android 4.1 or higher.

API 16+ use:

```
finishAffinity();
```

Below API 16 use:

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this); //with v4 support library
```

To exit whole app:

```
finishAffinity(); // Close all activites
System.exit(0);  // Releasing resources
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometime `finish()` not working

I have solved that issue with

`finishAffinity()`

Do not use

```
System.exit(0);
```

It will finish app without annimation.

Answer (score 2):

To clear all the activities while opening new one then do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:noHistory="true"` in your activity manifest file.

Comment: I bet he wants to go back to previous screen when he presses back, but close them only when he's on Home screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can try starting the Screen 3 with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK

Answer (score 1):

Hi if  you are in a fragment and are not able to use the finish method as it is(because finish should solve your problem) then you can use the `getActivity.finish()` method after `startActivity(intent);`.
If you  are not in a fragment you could directly use `finish()` after you `startActivity(intent);` line

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for solve your problem

1) call finish() after startActivity(intent) in every activity

2) set android:launchMode="singleInstance" in every  tag in menifest file

i think 2nd way is best for solving problem but you can also use first way