# Android rotate a View only by 90 degrees

Tags: android, rotation

I have twoo views. I want to rotate one view by 90 degrees, is it possible? My view is an Admob View. My admobview now shows on the screens left. Picture:

[image]

I d like to rotate that view by 90 degrees, to my view's bottom. Is it possible?
I have a code, but is not working, and when the admob is refreshing than the views state change to the original state.:(

**Edit: I am in portrait mode** and i dont want to change it to landscape, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not want to change to landscape, but that doesn't change the fact that it's the right answer. ;)

Honeycomb devices use the current orientation to orient the system bar at the bottom of the screen even when your app asks for full-screen mode. This is also used to orient screenshots for the recent task switcher, and it will probably continue to be used for more things like this in the future.

You can write a trivial custom parent view that will rotate the measurement, layout, and drawing to handle your current problem, but the right answer is still to run your app in landscape mode. Your app will be broken in a number of ways that you will not be able to hack around if you continue down this path.

Comment: yeah i know the corrent way to set up portrait mode, but the game written in landscape mode :(

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode but substitute "landscape" for "portrait" in the answers given. :)

Comment: I have to rewrite my all code, so LANDSCAPE mode was the correct, thanks.