# How can i block my layouts vertically? (i want that they can't be showed horizontally in the phone)

Tags: android, layout

How can i block my layouts vertically?

i want that they can't be showed horizontally in the phone when the phone user puts his phone horizontally

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode

Comment: Keep in mind that this will be a really bad experience for users with phone's that have keyboards, since they tend to use the phone in landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fixe the orientation of each activity on **portrait Mode**

Comment: yes, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode