# Could a layout exist only in layout-land folder?

Tags: android, layout, landscape, portrait

My application is forced to work only in landscape mode (**EDIT**: I mean, the activities has `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` in the manifest). So, I have the layouts in the layout-land folder, and there is not a same named resource in the default portrait folder.

Sometimes, when I left my device alone for few minuts and I wake it up, I get a forced close, showing a "not resource found" in the `setContentView` method.

I am guessing that in some conditions, android is looking for a portrait resource before noticing that it only needs the landscape layout. Is always mandatory to have a layout resource in the default portrait folder?

EDIT 2: I am not asking how to force an activity to show in portrait mode, I am asking if not having the corresponding portrait resource is a potential stability problem.

Comment: Have u tried android:screenOrientation="landscape"..???

Comment: You can set the default orietation in your manufest.xml <activity android:name=".YourActivity"  android:screenOrientation="landscape" "/>

Comment: You can set application landscape mode from manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi  please have a read

**layout:** it is all about general layouts

**layout-port:** it is all about a layout for widget that must change for portrait orientation

**layout-land:** it is all about alayout for widget that must change for landscape orientation

If in any case if you are in a landscape/portrait mode. Android firstly looks for the layout file in either the -portrait or -landscape directory first respectively, if it's not found then it will be back to the default layout directory to look.

There is no need to put layouts in layout-land folder if you know that you will be  be using the landscape mode only. Use the default layout folder simply

what you can do is in yours case is

You can set the default orientation in your androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YoursActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" "/>
```

by means you can write and go for

```
<activity
        android:name=".YoursActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscapre" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default orietation in your manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" "/>
```

You can also go for both programmatically as follows:

```
   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But by default, the layouts in `/res/layout` are applied to both **portrait** and **landscape**.

**EDIT :**

Also you should keep the **same name** of ressources in layout (dafault) and layout-land folder( you will keep your landscape adjusted layouts)

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to put your layouts in layout-land folder if you know y'd be using the landscape mode only. Use the default layout folder and set the orientation to landscape in the manifest file for all your activities.

```
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only landscape mode in Your activities You need to add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` for each activity in AndroidManifest.xml file. For example:

```
<activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

After that no matter where you store Your layouts in `/layout-land` folder or simple `/layout` folder

Comment: please check your example code it should be `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Answer (score 0):

set your application to landscape only. Then you will not need different layout folders, just have one.

In your manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ExampleActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also see this theread

[How to set entire application in portrait mode only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/android-how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only)