# How to enable/disable orientation change only for my app?

Tags: android

Using code below, I can enable or disable auto-rotation for whole device

```
Settings.System.putInt(
    getActivity().getContentResolver(),
    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 
    orientationEnabled //0 means off, 1 means on
);
```

How can I do same but restricted to my app? I dont want to change global settings forcing user to restore them, after he used my app.

EDIT:
I want to change that setting on runtime, not to lock it permanently.
E.g at some point to enable auto rotation, so use can change orientation, if he want, but not to force him (thus this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9784269/1551603) does not fit).

Comment: Do you mean this : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode] ?

Comment: Or this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only/9784269#9784269

Comment: @hkN , Sorry for incompletness. I updated my question

Comment: @appoll Sorry for incompletness. I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To temporally disable orientation changes in an Activity call this:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

and then to re-enable orientation changes call:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Comment: great, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

U can enable/disable screen rotation in AndroidManifest inside activity tag

Like this

```
 <activity
           ---
            android:screenOrientation="locked"
           ----  />
```

All screenOrientation options

```
android:screenOrientation=["unspecified" | "behind" |
                                     "landscape" | "portrait" |
                                     "reverseLandscape" | "reversePortrait" |
                                     "sensorLandscape" | "sensorPortrait" |
                                     "userLandscape" | "userPortrait" |
                                     "sensor" | "fullSensor" | "nosensor" |
                                     "user" | "fullUser" | "locked"]
```

Hope this will help you.