# MVVM Cross android orientation issue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i need to change the orientation as per tablet (both orientations) for Phone (only portriat) , kindly let me know the ways to do it in MVVM Cross in Android

[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/AppTheme")]

Answer (score 0):

Put this bool resource in `res/values` as `devices_config.xml` or whatever (file names don't matter here):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Put this one in `res/values-sw600dp` and `res/values-xlarge`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="portrait_only">false</bool>
</resources>
```

Then, in the `OnCreate` method of your Activities you can do this:

```cs
if (Resources.GetBoolean(Resource.Boolean.portrait_only))
{
    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
}
```

Devices that are more than 600 dp in the smallest width direction, or x-large on pre-Android 3.2 devices (tablets, basically) will behave like normal, based on sensor and user-locked rotation, etc. Everything else (phones, pretty much) will be portrait only.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14793611/6248510)

Just in case, it's possible that you see some autorotations when changing activities, so if that's the case you can check [this answer to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42936007/activity-orientation-changes-automatically-on-android/46565259#46565259)

HIH