# How to disable landscape mode for entire application

Tags: android

I want to disable landscape mode for my entire application. I want to be able to do so without setting `screenOrientation` to portrait for each activity in my manifest. Is it possible to do it with one attribute?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only) Have a look, your problem will be solved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set entire application in portrait mode only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only)

Answer (score 6):

Simply, in the manifest file add android:screenOrientation to all the defined activities.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

It will make all your activities to stick only to portrait mode only. Just add the screenOrientation to all the activities.

Answer (score 1):

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` in onCreate() method. just create a BaseActivity and each your activity extends with this BaseActivity.

```
public SampleActivity extends BaseActivity{

}

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Edit

In Manifest

```
<activity
 android:name=".ui.hello.Activity"
 android:label="@string/apa_nama"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest, set this for all your activities:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

portrait oriented restrict your activity to change orientation to landscape. You have to put this line for each activity in Manifest file.