# Is there a way to put the whole Android App to landscape in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio, orientation

I have seen many answers to this question showing something like this:

```
<activity android:name="..."
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">

</activity>
```

But i wonder if there is a way i do not have to repeat

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

in every activity.

Is there a way to set this global?

Comment: I've always use android:screenOrientation="landscape", haven't seen other way to achieve that.

Comment: Yes, see Graham Borland's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24827944/6853453

Comment: You can do like this .


Let all Activity inherit from a `BaseActivity` and then write in `BaseActivity` `onCreate ()` method.



`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`