# XML/Android :screenOrientation only works at MainActivity?

Tags: android, xml

So I put screenOrientation="nosensor" (also tried portrait, as I want every activity only to be able to be vertically) in manifest file, but it only works in MainActivity, but when I change to another activity, it can rotate the page again, why is this happening, and what should I do?

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.frisbeecaddy">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewGame2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityResume" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewGame" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewCourse" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityCourses" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityPlayers" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="nosensor">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set entire application in portrait mode only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745797/how-to-set-entire-application-in-portrait-mode-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this line in all of your activities.

```
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
```

for example in your code:-

```
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewGame2"
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityResume"
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor" />
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewGame" 
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityNewCourse" 
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityCourses" 
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityPlayers" 
                  android:screenOrientation="nosensor"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that I have to give that separately for every activity.

Comment: We always learn from our mistakes. Glad it's helped you to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the orientation for every activity.

`android:screenOrientation="nosensor"`