# How to get landscape view for splash screen in Android using Titanium?

Tags: android, orientation, titanium, splash-screen

How do i get a slash screen default mode set to landscape in Titanium. In my app i tried

```
Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT;
var NavigationController = require('NavigationController').NavigationController;
var windows = require('window_js').windows;
```

and in window_js.js its

```
exports.windows = function(navController){
 var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
    navBarHidden : true,
    fullscreen:true
 });
   return window;
};
```

But this code shows an error  Wrapped java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException (file:///android_asset/Resources/app.js#1)

and afterremovinf line 1 i.e.

```
Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT;
```

App starts in portrait mode and splash screen quickly changes to the landscape mode. What is the possible solution for this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splash screen in landscape mode is goto android project folder

**Project** ---> **Build** ---- > **Android** ------> **AndroidManifest.xml** file .

Copy **AndroidMenifest.xml** file text and put in **AndroidManifest.custom.xml** file in same folder where AndroidManifest.xml file is kept.

In activity tag write

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape" for landscape mode
```

and replace

```
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

to

```
  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
```

in whole file in each activity .
Example

```
<activity>
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
</activity>
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

i would try to set the landscape orientation in the [android manifest xml /tiapp.xml](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Maintaining+a+Custom+AndroidManifest.xml) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode):

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

and then i would change the orientation in your js back to portrait.

```
Titanium.UI.orientation = Titanium.UI.PORTRAIT;
```