# Ensure screen orientation is fixed to portrait and NEVER changes

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I would like my Android app to instantiate it's home screen activity one time only. I am managing the back stack appropriately to achieve this but have just discovered an orientation issue when the app starts up.

Visually this orientation change only shows itself on the emulator. (probably runs too fast to be observed on a device).

Here's what happens :: -->

```
activity.onCreate()
activity.onDestroy()
activity.onCreate()
```

This sequence makes sense and is caused by the change in orientation. What does not make sense  (to me) is that it happens at all because I have done the following to prevent an orientation change :: -->

AndroidManifest.xml contains

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

for all my activities and in the home screen activity onCreate() method, I'm calling

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

So why do I get an orientation change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in your manifest file where you declare your activity like this

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivity"
          ....
          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

if you want to do using java code 
try

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

before you `setContentView` for your activity in `onCreate()`

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode/12618558#12618558)

Comment: The only thing I was doing differently was calling the setRequestedOrientation after the setContentView. It seems to make no difference whether it comes after or before. Seems that your answer is the correct one though so I must be doing soemthing else wrong to cause the onDestroy. Thanks for the help.