# Image loading from dreawable folder using array

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button1;
        final ImageView image;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int j=0;
                while(j<=4){
                    int res=getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j,"drawable",getPackageName());
                    image.setBackgroundResource(res);
                    j = j+1;
                }
            }
        });

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. What is wrong with this code this code only show 1st and last image? how I can fix it?
2. I don't want to rotate my apps. How I can do that?
3. How I can mentioned a user in Stack Vverflow? I tried `@username` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for question 1:** `What is wrong with this code this code only show 1st and last image? how I can fix it?`

Put the `int j` outside the onClick and change the `while` to an `if`

```
int j=0;
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(j >= 0 && j <= 4){
            int res = getResources().getIdentifier("d002_p00"+j, "drawable", getPackageName());
            image.setBackgroundResource(res);
            j++;
        }
    }
});
```

**Answer for question 2:** `I don't want to rotate my apps. How I can do that?`

[See this answer of another stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582585/1682559)

**Answer for question 3:** `How I can mentioned a user in Stack Vverflow? I tried @username but it didn't work.`

I don't know for sure myself, but I think you can't use @user_name to reply a comment when there is only one commenter apart from yourself (at least I couldn't). If you want to credit someone however, I would suggest putting their profile-page in a link like so: [@user3546792](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3102913/user3102913)  (Click their name, copy the link, click the `Add Hyperlink`-button in SO and paste the copied link. Then change `[enter link description here]` to `[@user_name]`

Answer (score -1):

For question 2:

```
 I don't want to rotate my apps. How I can do that?
```

Your just add this in your android Manifest:

```
android:orientation="portrait"
```