# Lock only to portrait view

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

This is my manifest.xml code:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.SearchActivity"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

And i have added the follwoing code in my activity :

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      // ignore orientation/keyboard change
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Though i have done this two things my device is changing its oreientaion whenever it's go from portrait to landscape and vice versa. I want to lock it only to portrait view. But it is not doing that. What things should i change here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - disable landscape mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode)

Comment: remove `android:configChanges` `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`  this will do.

Comment: Rustam i have removed andorid:configChanges from manifest now only android:screenOrientation tehre. BUt still the problem exist.