# How to prevent display from rotating with Android?

Tags: android, orientation

How can I prevent the screen from rotating between landscape and portrait orientation ?

Comment: Question is similar as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode

Comment: In your manifest you can set your activities orientation with android:screenOrientation="portrait" or if you want landscape do that. But this is in the basic documentation...

Answer (score 1):

Basically add this line in your manifest file

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

android:orientation="horizontal" or vertical if you want it upright