# Last Activity orientation changed when new activity orientation in landscape

Tags: android-activity, screen-orientation

I have Two Activities A and B orientation of A is fixed in Portrait and B orientation can be change in landscape and portrait.When user at Activity B and change orientation in landscape this also change orientation of Activity A in landscape why ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you write the the orientation At Manifest like  android:screenOrientation="portrait"

or write in your Activity setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: is there any error shows logcat? refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode