# Android ScreenOrientation behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, landscape-portrait

I got an activity which I want to always remain with portrait layout. I got these settings in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="Main"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing">
```

This settings makes the activity just load the portrait layout to the side if I turn the device on the side. I want the layout to just remain in the portrait position and that's it even though it means viewing the layout on the side when switching the device 90 degrees.

Comment: Already answered here :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force it dynamically:

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

Comment: Put this line in the Activity's onCreate().

Answer (score 3):

From Android 3.2 onwards, you also need to add `screenSize` to `configChanges`

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

From the developer docs at [handling runtime changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

> **Caution**: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "**screen size**" also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape orientation.