# App crash when I change the device orientation

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image: In graph i plot value from calling api.]
I have display this `graph` in fragment class and when I change the orientation app will crash. How can I change orientation and display image in `landscape` mode without crashing an app.

Comment: Can you share the error message you get when the app crashes?

Comment: @Rachit the terminal provide this error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference.

Answer (score 13):

When the orientation change then the state of fragment will be changed. You need to save the state of your fragment by calling

```
setRetainInstance(true);
```

in `onCreate()` method.

You can also use `onRestoreInstanceState()` method which will store your `savedInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

The best solution is just add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHideen"
```

for your activity which holds the fragment in your manifest file.

Comment: Worked for me: android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHideen"

My app was crashing when I tried to change orientation. The log keeps trying to say something like:

TypeError: _reactNative.DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener is not a function. (In '_reactNative.DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener('didUpdateDimensions', this.handleDimensionsUpdate)', '_reactNative.DeviceEventEmitter.removeListener' is undefined)
                                                             
This error is located at:
in ReactNativeModal (at CustomisableAlert.js:121)

Answer (score 1):

During orientation changes, android destroys your activity. Maybe you set something and it became invalid during that change.
You can read more about it here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

You said you want to be able to change the orientation. Just for completeness, you can fix the orientation to landscape or portrait, see:
[Android - disable landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode)