# Instant App screen orientation

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

How can I disable screen orientation in Android Instant app???

I used 
***`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`***
in every Manifest file (in 3 files) but it doens`t help!

Comment: share your code snippet.

Comment: do you want to fix the orientation in portrait or leave it upon the device's orientation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - disable landscape mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582185/android-disable-landscape-mode)

Comment: FIXED!)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting the bug Igor. The fix for setting screenOrientation through Manifest in instant apps is coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like
   From Fragment

```
 getActivity().setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);  // programmatically
```

From Activity

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```