# Is there any way to make a layout inside a fragment fixed to portrait while in landscape mode?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, fragment, orientation

I have a fragment in which, when in landscape mode need to show another layout, while in portrait another layout?
Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

My requirement is my bottom menu should be locked in portrait even when the orientation changes.

As my center view has been rotated, others are not changed.

Is it possible in android, if yes, how to implement it?

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/582185/9636037. Is your question the same as that one?

Comment: no actually, I have a layout(resembiling a bottom menu) aligned to bottom inside the fragment which gets rotated on landscape mode, so is there any way to restrict that rotation of that particular view?

Answer (score 0):

In your `res` folder, create `layout-land` folder. Create an `xml` layout file with the same name as the layout you are currently using for your fragment. In the newly created layout file, define your landscape layout.

Comment: actually i have tried that ,when orientation changes it is not using that layout in land-layout folder. i have used the same name as the layout im currenty using in portrait.